# Pass answer through query string to Limesurvey survey

Tags: parameters, limesurvey

Is it possible to send answers through query string? something like this:

```
HTTP://survey/1?ASW1=test
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, please refer to the manual - https://manual.limesurvey.org/Workarounds:_Survey_behaviour#Prefilling_survey_elements

Comment: Thanks, version 2.x needs to be something like https://surveys.url/surveys/index.php/xxx/newtest/Y/718973X4X4/value